# How to exclude first and last row of a table when getting table size

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a table with header(1row) and footer(1 row). i am getting the table size and expect value as 50 but it returns 52 as it count both header and footer  row. Is there a way i can exclude the header and footer row with in my code and get the actual expected value. Here is my code to get the table size

```
public int getTableSize() throws InterruptedException{
    List<WebElement> columnElements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("table[class='table table-bordered table-hover ng-isolate-scope']>tbody>tr"));
  return  columnElements.size();
}
```

Comment: Can't you just remove the first and last items of `columnElements `?

Comment: "return  columnElements.size()-2;"

Answer (score 2):

You can use :not in your selector to negate the first-child and last-child

```
table[class='table table-bordered table-hover ng-isolate-scope']>tbody>tr:not(:first-child):not(:last-child)
```

Answer (score 0):

The most effective (or cheapest) way is to substract the number of elements to be removed, in your case the method should look like:

```
    public int getTableSize() throws InterruptedException{
        List<WebElement> columnElements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("table[class='table table-bordered table-hover ng-isolate-scope']>tbody>tr"));
        return  columnElements.size() - 2;
    }
```

I strongly recommend this as the primary solution because of the performance issues. For me, it's hard to imagine a situation where there's a need for a more complicated solution.

Comment: You should also rename your method so it would not cause any confusions in your documentation. This especially concerns you if you end up using koga73's solution.